# polymer share component property structure

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

If I have the following polymer element, how do I let the users of this element know about the structure of the object in dataSource. i.e If I have to declare and share `Employee` function, so that they can `new Employee()` and create an array. Whats the polymer way of sharing common data objects? Some seem to suggest behavior, but this isn't a behavior of the component, this is a data object with properties and no behavior.

```
<dom-module id="employee-list"> 
  <template>
          <ul>
              <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{ dataSource }}">
                  <li>
                     <span>{{item.firstName}}</span>
                  </li>
              </template>
          </ul>          
  </template>
  <script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'employee-list',
    properties: {
        dataSource: {
            type: Array,
            value: [{ firstName: "First 1", lastName: "Last 1" }]
        }
    }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use behaviors! Although the name is misleading, you can use behaviors to share properties.

> A behavior is an object that looks similar to a typical Polymer
>   prototype. A behavior can define lifecycle callbacks, **declared
>   properties**, default attributes, observers, and listeners.

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/behaviors.html

JS Bin example: http://jsbin.com/vuqumo/edit?html,output

Answer (score -1):

Your users are going to use your element like this

```
<employee-list datasource="[[usersEmployeeList]]"></employee-list>
```

You need to tell them the format of the datasource in a jsdoc comment on the property.  I don't know the format of the jsdoc comments properly, but look at the way the existing polymer elements do it.